# How to match values of 2 array in Jquery /Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 lists if a list2 value equal to  list1 value then I want to add a class to the HTML option with matched values.

```js
// var list1 = $('select#workers option').toArray().map(item => item.value);

list1 = ["19", "78", "73", "26", "79", "93", "63", "70", "82", "60", "42", "90", "91", "84", "92", "64", "1", "83", "85", "61", "21", "45"];
list2=  ["93", "78", "91", "60", "83", "90", "84", "79", "82", "42"];


$.each(list1, function( index, value ) {
  var list1val = value;
$.each(list2, function( index, value ) {
var list2val = value;
   if(list1val==list2val){
   
     //  $('select#workers option').addClass('green');
    console.log('Add class');
    }
    else{   $('select#workers option').addClass('red');  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="workers" multiple="" size="5">
    <option value="19">Administration</option>
    <option value="78">Alan  </option>
    <option value="73">Allister </option>
    <option value="26">Andrew  </option>
    <option value="79">Chris </option>
    <option value="93">Clayton </option>
    <option value="63">Dale Morcom</option>
    <option value="70">David </option>
    <option value="82">Dean </option>
    <option value="60">Deano </option>
    <option value="42">Drew </option>
    <option value="90">Gabriel </option>
    <option value="91"> Grant</option>
    <option value="84">Jeremy Beeston</option>
    <option value="92"> Rolfe</option>
    <option value="64"> Johnson</option>
    <option value="1">Luke </option>
    <option value="83">Matt </option>
    <option value="85">Michelle </option>
    <option value="61">Playsafe</option>
    <option value="21">Squizzy </option>
    <option value="45">Stuart </option>
</select>
```

I want to add a class to the option which have matched values from list 2.

but `$('select#workers option').addClass('green');` is adding class to all options.

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute selector:

```
$("select#workers option[value='" + list1val + "']").addClass("green");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding class based on attribute `value`.

```js
list1 = ["19", "78", "73", "26", "79", "93", "63", "70", "82", "60", "42", "90", "91", "84", "92", "64", "1", "83", "85", "61", "21", "45"];
list2=  ["93", "78", "91", "60", "83", "90", "84", "79", "82", "42"];


$.each(list1, function( index, value ) {
  var list1val = value;
$.each(list2, function( index, value ) {
var list2val = value;
   if(list1val==list2val){

     $('select#workers option[value = '+list2val+']').addClass('green');
      console.log('Add class');
    }
    else{   
      $('select#workers option[value = '+list2val+']').addClass('red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="workers" multiple="" size="5">
  <option value="19">Administration</option>
  <option value="78">Alan  </option>
  <option value="73">Allister </option>
  <option value="26">Andrew  </option>
  <option value="79">Chris </option>
  <option value="93">Clayton </option>
  <option value="63">Dale Morcom</option>
  <option value="70">David </option>
  <option value="82">Dean </option>
  <option value="60">Deano </option>
  <option value="42">Drew </option>
  <option value="90">Gabriel </option>
  <option value="91"> Grant</option>
  <option value="84">Jeremy Beeston</option>
  <option value="92"> Rolfe</option>
  <option value="64"> Johnson</option>
  <option value="1">Luke </option>
  <option value="83">Matt </option>
  <option value="85">Michelle </option>
  <option value="61">Playsafe</option>
  <option value="21">Squizzy </option>
  <option value="45">Stuart </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the matches list first with O(n + m) time complexity instead of nested loop O(n^2)

```
var list1 = ["19", "78", "73", "26", "79", "93", "63", "70", "82", "60", "42", "90", "91", "84", "92", "64", "1", "83", "85", "61", "21", "45"];
var list2=  ["93", "78", "91", "60", "83", "90", "84", "79", "82", "42"];

var mapList1 = {};
list1.forEach(function(value) {
    mapList1[value] = true;
});

var matches = [];
list2.forEach(function(value) {
    if (mapList1[value]) {
    matches.push(value);
  }
});
console.log(matches)
```

Then you can use matches to highlight by adding class

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list1 = ["19", "78", "73", "26", "79", "93", "63", "70", "82", "60", "42", "90", "91", "84", "92", "64", "1", "83", "85", "61", "21", "45"];
    list2=  ["93", "78", "91", "60", "83", "90", "84", "79", "82", "42"];

    var found = list1.find(function(element) {

            for(var i = list2.length; i--;) {

                 if(list2[i] === element)
                      console.log(true);
                }
       console.log(false);
    });
```